# Javascript: constant properties

Tags: javascript, object, constants

In javascript, can I declare properties of an object to be constant?

Here is an example object:

```
   var XU = {
      Cc: Components.classes
   };
```

or

```
   function aXU()
   {
      this.Cc = Components.classes;
   }

   var XU = new aXU();
```

just putting "const" in front of it, doesn't work.

I know, that i could declare a function with the same name (which would be also kind of constant), but I am looking for a simpler and more readable way.

Browser-compatibility is not important. It just has to work on the Mozilla platform, as it is for a Xulrunner project.

Thank you a lot!

Cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you only need it to work on the Mozilla platform, you can define a getter with no corresponding setter. The best way to do it is different for each of your examples.

#### In an object literal, there is a special syntax for it:

```
var XU = {
    get Cc() { return Components.classes; }
};
```

In your second exampe, you can use the `__defineGetter__` method to add it to either `aXU.prototype` or to `this` inside the constructor. Which way is better depends on whether the value is different for each instance of the object.

**Edit:** To help with the readability problem, you could write a function like `defineConstant` to hide the uglyness.

```
function defineConstant(obj, name, value) {
    obj.__defineGetter__(name, function() { return value; });
}
```

Also, if you want to throw an error if you try to assign to it, you can define a setter that just throws an Error object:

```
function defineConstant(obj, name, value) {
    obj.__defineGetter__(name, function() { return value; });
    obj.__defineSetter__(name, function() {
        throw new Error(name + " is a constant");
    });
}
```

#### If all the instances have the same value:

```
function aXU() {
}

defineConstant(aXU.prototype, "Cc", Components.classes);
```

#### or, if the value depends on the object:

```
function aXU() {
    // Cc_value could be different for each instance
    var Cc_value = return Components.classes;

    defineConstant(this, "Cc", Cc_value);
}
```

For more details, you can read the [Mozilla Developer Center documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide:Creating_New_Objects:Defining_Getters_and_Setters).

Comment: This is actually what I did in the end, although it lacks readability. I also defined a setter that doesn't do anything. I got that from another thread, but from your example the setter doesn't seem to be necessary. So I removed it. Thanks to you all!

Comment: Good point about the readability. You could write a defineConstant function or something like that to help.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks a lot. I am using with a global variable `GVars` which declare as a global constance. Then, I use your function to add getter and setter as a field of this `GVars`. I need to do this because I want to create global constance which value assigned after jQuery function. It is such an excellent solution. Thank you very much. (I will give you more than one vote if I can.)

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**: This works!

```
const FIXED_VALUE = 37;
FIXED_VALUE = 43;
alert(FIXED_VALUE);//alerts "37"
```

Technically I think the answer is no (Until [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Statements:const) makes it into the wild). You can provide wrappers and such, but when it all boils down to it, you can redefine/reset the variable value at any time.

The closest I think you'll get is defining a "constant" on a "class".

```
// Create the class
function TheClass(){
}

// Create the class constant
TheClass.THE_CONSTANT = 42;

// Create a function for TheClass to alert the constant
TheClass.prototype.alertConstant = function(){
  // You can’t access it using this.THE_CONSTANT;
  alert(TheClass.THE_CONSTANT);
}

// Alert the class constant from outside
alert(TheClass.THE_CONSTANT);

// Alert the class constant from inside
var theObject = new TheClass();
theObject.alertConstant();
```

However, the "class" **TheClass** itself can be redefined later on

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Javascript 1.5 (in XUL for example), you can use the `const` keyword instead of `var` to declare a constant.

The problem is that it cannot be a property of an object. You can try to limit its scope by namespacing it inside a function.

```
(function(){ 

const XUL_CC = Components.classes;

// Use the constant here

})()
```

Answer (score 0):

To define a constant property, you could set the writable attribute to false in the defineProperty method as shown below:

**Code snippet:**

```
var XU = {};

Object.defineProperty(XU, 'Cc', {
    value: 5,
    writable: false
});

XU.Cc = 345;

console.log(XU.Cc);
```

**Result:**

```
5           # The value hasn't changed
```