# How to define a const outside of the current scope/block?

Tags: javascript, scope, try-catch, constants

I'm writing code somewhat like this:

```
try {
    const row = functionToGetStuffFromDatabase('SQL QUERY here');
} catch (err) {
    functionToDealWithError('Error: ' + err);
}
functionToProcessDatabaseResult(row);
```

However, I can't access `row` and pass it as an argument to `processDatabaseResult` because it's defined within the scope of the `try` block. And, I can't define it outside of the try block and set it inside of the block because I can't change a `const`. I understand I could just use a normal variable, but I was wondering if there is any way to do this with `const`s?

Comment: Any reason you aren't calling `processDatabaseResult` inside the scope of the `try`?

Comment: I would like to be able to deal with a database query error in a different way than an error resulting from processing the data.

Comment: My best guess was to try something like `const window.myVar = value`, but that actually throws an error. The [next-best thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906643/javascript-constant-properties) I've found is making a custom object and defining a getter on it without a corresponding setter, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Because of block scoping you won't be able to do this exactly as you have written it.

You could try rearranging your code a little.

```
function functionToGetStuffFromDatabase(query){
    try {
       doDatabaseQuery(query)
    } catch (err) {
       functionToDealWithError('Error: ' + err);
    }
}

const row = functionToGetStuffFromDatabase('SQL QUERY here');
functionToProcessDatabaseResult(row);
```

Comment: The problem here is that the result from `doDatabaseQuery` isn't being returned from `functionToGetStuffFromDatabase`. And inserting a return statement will end the function before it can get to the `catch` block

Comment: Is your query to the database actually an async function needing you to pass a callback?

Comment: I'm using using some fancy node libraries (pg-promise and asyncawait) which make the DB query act as a synchronous function. So, for all practical purposes, it's synchronous.

Comment: If it was me I would be handling the possible exceptions from the database call using the promise.catch handler. However, my personal preference would be to avoid the async await abstraction and just stick with promises.

Comment: Well in my opinion promises just aren't powerful and flexible enough for even fairly basic use cases, for example there's no good way to break out of a chain, pass results down a chain multiple steps, and the errors thrown by unit testing assertions often are never thrown and can slip by unseen.

Comment: Those are valid points. Seems like your problem could easily be solved by them though.

Answer (score -1):

Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) for details.

Comment: I am aware of this, as I believe I made clear. This does not answer my question.